# JavaScript: из массива в GET строку

Tags: javascript

Есть массив(либо можно заменить на объект):

```js
arr = ["1", "4", "5", "7", '11'];
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как на JavaScript (желательно не Jquery) из этого массива я могу получить строку пригодную для передачи через URL строку?

Т.е., чтобы получилось:

```js
'name[]=1&name[]=4&name[]=5&name[]=7&name[]=11'
```

Comment: В простом случае можно `arr.join("&name[]=")` и недостающее добавить.

Comment: Хоть Вы и не хотите jquery, я все-таки упомяну jQuery.param

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Примерно так

```js
var arr = ["1", "4", "5", "7", '11'];
console.log(encodeURI('name[]=' + arr.join('&name[]=')));
```

Comment: нельзя квадратные скобки в url

Comment: @УмеренноУпоротаяУтка Добавил недостающее в ответ